# Executable file to share Outlook toolbar created using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, toolbar

I created an Outlook toolbar using VBA.

I want to share this configuration by using an executable file, so others can open the file and automatically have the new toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

VBA macros are not designed for distributing your solution to multiple machines. That is exactly what COM add-ins were designed for.

There is no converters that can do this part of work for you automatically. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx) to get started quickly. This walkthrough shows you how to create a VSTO Add-in for Microsoft Office Outlook.

You may consider creating a VB.NET based Outlook add-in. In that case you will avoid language translating issues. You may find the [Converting Code from VBA to Visual Basic .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa192490(v=office.11).aspx) article helpful. It presents issues to consider when converting your Microsoft Office solutions from Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) to Visual Basic .NET. Provides a general overview of their differences, and then uses examples from Word and Excel to describe how you can use Visual Studio Tools for the Microsoft Office System to convert your code.